# Can't translate abstract expression property into Entity Framework filtered IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services

I am developing a generic controller for CRUD operations of a web service. I have created the `IEntity` and `IDTO` interfaces to have the necessary abstraction to operate generically.

These are the relevant methods of the abstract class `CRUDController`:

```
namespace Api.Controllers;

public abstract class CRUDController<Entity, DTO> : ControllerBase
    where Entity : class, IEntity
    where DTO : class, IDTO
{
    protected readonly IContext _dbContext;
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public abstract Expression<Func<Entity, object>> UniqueIdentifier { get; }

    public CRUDController(IContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    async Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetEntities()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<Entity>().ToListAsync();
    }

    async Task<Entity?> GetEntity(string key)
    {
        var result = await _dbContext.Set<Entity>().Where(e => UniqueIdentifier.Compile()(e).Equals(key)).ToListAsync();
        
        if (result.Count == 0)
            return null;

        if (result.Count > 1)
            throw new Exception("Key duplication");
        
        return result[0];
    }
    // ...
}
```

And an example of one of its implementations:

```
namespace Api.Controllers;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProtocolController : CRUDController<Protocol, ProtocolDTO>
{
    public ProtocolController(IContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
        : base(dbContext, mapper) { }

    public override Expression<Func<Protocol, object>> UniqueIdentifier
        => p => p.Id;

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        => await Read(); //Operation defined in CRUDController, works perfectly

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get/{key}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string key)
        => await Read(key); //Error message captured in this call, where UniqueIdentifier is compiled

    // ...
}
```

Everything is fine except for defining outside the controller which property of the `IEntity` should be used as the primary key when filtering in the `DbSet`.

When running tests, I get the following error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n    .Where(a => Invoke(__Compile_0, a).Equals(__key_1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Any suggestions on how to define which property should be used to identify each `IEntity` instance?

Thanks in advance

I used a variation of the `GetEntities()` method to do the filtering, but realized that I was retrieving all the tuples from the database to memory to then filter, so building the query on `IQueryable` seems ideal.